# Image magic TIFF Warning

Tags: imagemagick

Am trying to run a simple .eps to .png conversion using image magic convert.exe,

IF EXIST test.eps convert.exe test.eps test.png

I see the error :

convert.exe: Invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectoryCheckOrder' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/960.

I do not have TIFF image inside the folder nor am trying to convert TIFF image. Why am I seeing this error?

Comment: The eps vector file may have an embedded tiff raster image

Comment: Thanks you , running  identity.exe  on images shows 
test[1] TIFF 67x23 67x23+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 3232B 0.000u 0:00.012
Looks like issue with image ..